# What does it mean when you say that one's eyes "swept over" someone?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is it just a fancier way of saying that you're looking at them?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the motion of **sweeping** and uses it figuratively to describe the nature of the looking.  A wave can sweep over a beach.  Wind can sweep over the plain. A brush can sweep across the floor.  The person was not taken in by the eyes as a *gestalt*; rather, the gaze passed over them.

Comment: Ah, I see: it's a brief action on the observer's part.

Comment: @Googly-Eyed-Rock - I would say that if your eyes swept over someone, you looked at more than one part of them, in a sequence (e.g. from head to toe, side to side, etc), rather than just gazing at one part, such as their eyes or face. Essentially, _your eyes moved_. British people, maybe others as well, may say 'he looked me up and down' when they mean that they think someone has given them a disapproving look.

Comment: Usually, but not necessarily, brief.  Brevity is not entailed in the figurative use of **sweep**.  In photographic terms, it is a "pan" but on the vertical axis.  Unless the person being looked at is reclining :-)

Comment: Just to be clear, to say that the eyes sweep over a person is different than "looking them up and down". The two phrases have very different connotations.

Comment: I was also wondering about this, if the phrase was an alternate version of "looking someone up and down." There is a difference, then. That's good to know.

Comment: Looking someone up and down is an assessment of some kind.  *The governess looked the children up and down. The boy's fingernails were dirty and the girl's nose was running.* or *The angry motorists got out of their cars and looked each other up and down.*

Comment: @Googly-Eyed-Rock It's interesting that it was (presumably?) used about one person; it might be more common about a group, like "The general's eyes swept over the assembled army." I could also take the meaning either to be the the looker "overlooked" the subject without paying much detailed attention, or to be that they looked over them very thoroughly. I presume the context and tone would clarify.

Comment: @TimR - I can imagine a sub-Mickey Spillane pulp writer doing something like this: 'The dame came into my office. "Are you a private detective?" she asked. I looked her up and down, and up, and down, and spent some time around the middle. "Yes", I replied.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Or "My eyes swept over her and then I looked her up and down in case I'd missed anything."

Comment: I just want to clarify something: I meant "from head to toe", concerning the phrase "looking someone up and down". I wasn't thinking of a judgemental or disapproving look. Anyway, I appreciate the answers you guys have provided! Very helpful. :)